# Date invalid when no match is found in DB2

Tags: sql, db2-400

I'm running a very simple DB2 query which is giving me a timestamp error because it can't find records with 2019-02-29 and so it's returning an invalid date type. If I change it to 2019-02-28 then it works.

I can't seem to find a proper "CASE WHEN" use for this, but is there a simple way to not interfere with current functionality but to say "If this date isn't found just ignore today's date"?

I need it to run even if there are nor prior year records for 02-29

```
SELECT 'DATE' AS RANGE, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM datesTable
WHERE user = 123
AND newDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-02-29'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* a `case` should work:

```
newDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND 
        (CASE WHEN '2019-02-29' <> '2019-02-29' THEN '2019-02-29' END)
```

This assumes that you are constructing the value somehow, based on the current date.

The problem is because the column is a date so the operands to `BETWEEN` are all converted to dates.  The `case` comparison should get around this, by only converting when the data is not the forbidden date.

Or, do the comparisons as strings:

```
where varchar_format(newDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') between '2019-01-01' AND '2019-02-29'
```

No conversion to date is happening here, so no error should occur.  That said, this will prevent the use of an index on `newDate`.

Comment: I think that makes sense, it is using a php variable to get that date. So tomorrow the comparison will be false, and the last part after 'THEN' will have the current date variable for tomorrow and return the correct count. This seems to work as I've run it so far, thank you!

Comment: So in the case statement, I can plug the variable into the first and third dates but leave the second date as 02-29?

Comment: @TomN. . . . Yes.  The *definition* of `case` in the standard is that the `when` clause is only evaluated when the `then` is true.  I'm not 100% sure that DB2 (or any other particular database) adheres to this 100% of the time.  It is worth trying.  Otherwise, the string version will do what you want.